# Improve performance of Perl search file script

Tags: regex, perl, perl-data-structures

I have recently noticed that a quick script I had written in Perl that was designed to be used on sub 10MB files has been modified, re-tasked and used in 40MB+ text files with significant performance issues in a batch environment.

The jobs have been running for about 12 hours per run when encountering a large text file and I am wondering how do I improve the perfomance of the code? Should I slurp the file into memory and if I do it will break the jobs reliance on the line numbers in the file. Any constructive thought would be greatly appreciated, I know the job is looping through the file too many times but how to reduce that?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = "$ARGV[0]"; # This is needed for regular batch use 
my $cancfile = "$ARGV[1]"; # This is needed for regular batch use 
my @num =();
open(FILE, "<", "$filename") || error("Cannot open file ($!)");
while (<FILE>)
{
    push (@num, $.) if (/^P\|/)
}
close FILE;

my $start;
my $end;

my $loop = scalar(@num);
my $counter =1;
my $test;

open (OUTCANC, ">>$cancfile") || error ("Could not open file: ($!)");

#Lets print out the letters minus the CANCEL letters
for ( 1 .. $loop )
{
    $start = shift(@num) if ( ! $start );
    $end = shift(@num);
    my $next = $end;
    $end--;
    my $exclude = "FALSE";

    open(FILE, "<", "$filename") || error("Cannot open file ($!)");
    while (<FILE>)
    {
        my $line = $_;
        $test = $. if ( eof );
        if ( $. == $start && $line =~ /^P\|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\|1I\|IR\|/)
        {
            print OUTCANC "$line";
            $exclude = "TRUECANC";
            next;
        }
        if ( $. >= $start && $. <= $end && $exclude =~ "TRUECANC")
        {
            print OUTCANC "$line";
        } elsif ( $. >= $start && $. <= $end && $exclude =~ "FALSE"){
            print $_;
        }
    }
    close FILE;
    $end = ++$test if ( $end < $start );
    $start = $next if ($next);
}


#Lets print the last letter in the file

my $exclude = "FALSE";

open(FILE, "<", "$filename") || error("Cannot open file ($!)");
while (<FILE>)
{
    my $line = $_;
    if ( $. == $start && $line =~ /^P\|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\|1I\|IR\|/)
    {
        $exclude = "TRUECANC";
        next;
    }
    if ( $. >= $start && $. <= $end && $exclude =~ "TRUECANC")
    {
        print OUTCANC "$line";
    } elsif ( $. >= $start && $. <= $end && $exclude =~ "FALSE"){
        print $_;
    }
}
close FILE;
close OUTCANC;


#----------------------------------------------------------------

sub message
{
    my $m = shift or return;
    print("$m\n");
}

sub error
{
    my $e = shift || 'unknown error';
    print("$0: $e\n");
    exit 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the script do? What is the typical input and what is the corresponding expected output?

Comment: maybe you can reduce code and drill down where the code performce is.. This way you will getting better answer, and maybe you will figure it out yourself :)

Comment: 40 MB file can easily stand in memory.

Comment: You might want to try this on [codereview.se] instead of here, where it's somewhat more on topic

Comment: `exclude` seems to only ever contain 2 different values, use a 0/1 flag  so you can test its value as a boolean instead of by textual matching in each line (for maintainability you can of course use manifest constants instead of 0/1 literals). another option might be to read the file in slurp mode (`{ local $/ = undef; $fcontent = <FILE>; }`, note the wrapping into a new block) and match against `$fcontent`, moving between matches using the `\G` anchor in your regexp.

Comment: @choroba - The script is removing specific records from a text file. Each record starts with "P|" header line but has no trailer(end) line. To further complicate each record contains a varying number of lines. For example: P|123456789|1I|IR|more data| 1|more data| 1|more data| 2|more data| 3|more data| 3|more data| 3|more data| 4|more data|. So this record has eight lines but could have more or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *are* some things that could speed the script up, like removing unneccessary regex usage.

- `/^P\|/` is equivalent to `"P|" eq substr $_, 0, 2`.
- `$foo =~ "BAR"` could be `-1 != index $foo, "BAR"`.

Then there is some repeated code. Factoring that out into a sub will not increase performance per se, but makes it easier to reason about the behaviour of the script.

There are a lot of unneccessary stringifications like `"$filename"` – `$filename` alone is sufficient.

But the worst offender would be this:

```
for ( 1 .. $loop ) {
  ...
  open FILE, "<", $filename or ...
  while (<FILE>) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

You only need to read that file in *once*, preferably into an array. You can the loop over the indices:

```
for ( 1 .. $loop ) {
  ...
  for my $i (0 .. $#file_contents) {
    my $line = $file_contents[$i];
    ... # swap $. for $i, but avoid off-by-one error
  }
  ...
}
```

Disk IO is *slow*, so cache where you can!

I also see that you are using the `$exclude` variable as a boolean with the values `FALSE` and `TRUECANC`. Why not `0` and `1`, so you can use it directly in a conditional?

You can factor out common tests in if/elsif:

```
if    (FOO && BAR) { THING_A }
elsif (FOO && BAZ) { THING_B }
```

should be

```
if (FOO) {
    if    (BAR) { THING_A }
    elsif (BAZ) { THING_B }
}
```

The `$. == $start && $line =~ /^P\|.../` test may be silly, because `$start` contains only the numbers of lines that start with `P|` – so the regex may be sufficient here.

#### Edit

If I have understood the script correctly then the following should yield a significant performance increase:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($filename, $cancfile) = @ARGV;
open my $fh, "<", $filename or die "$0: Couldn't open $filename: $!";

my (@num, @lines);
while (<$fh>)
{
    push @lines, $_;
    push @num, $#lines if "P|" eq substr $_, 0, 2;
}

open my $outcanc, ">>", $cancfile or die "$0: Couldn't open $cancfile: $!";

for my $i ( 0 .. $#num )
{
    my $start = $num[$i];
    my $end   = ($num[$i+1] // @lines) - 1;
    # pre v5.10:
    # my $end = (defined $num[$i+1] ? $num[$i+1] : @lines) - 1

    if ($lines[$start] =~ /^P[|][0-9]{9}[|]1I[|]IR[|]/) {
        print {$outcanc} @lines[$start .. $end];
    } else {
        print STDOUT     @lines[$start .. $end];
    }
}
```

The script is cleaned up. The file is cached in an array. Only the parts of the array are iterated that are actually needed – we are down to *O(n)* from the previous *O(n · m)*.

For your future scripts: Proving behaviour around loops and mutating variables is not impossible, but tedious and annoying. Realizing that

```
for (1 .. @num) {
  $start = shift @num unless $next;  # aka "do this only in the first iteration"
  $next = shift @num:
  $end = $next - 1:
  while (<FH>) {
    ...
    $test = $. if eof
    ...
  }
  $end = ++test if $end < $start;
  $start = $next if $next;
}
```

is actually all about circumventing a possible `undef` in the 2nd `shift` takes some time. Instead of testing for `eof` in the inner loop, we can just pick the line number after the loop, so we don't need `$test`. Then we get:

```
$start = shift @num;
for my $i (1 .. @num) {
  $end = $num[$i] - 1:

  while (<FH>) { ... }

  $end = $. + 1 if $end < $start;  # $end < $start only true if not defined $num[$i]
  $start = $num[$i] if $num[$i];
}
```

After translating `$i` down by one we confine the out-of-bounds problem to one point only:

```
for my $i (0 .. $#num) {
  $start = $num[$i];
  $end = $num[$i+1] - 1; # HERE: $end = -1 if $i == $#num

  while (<FH>) { ... }
}
$end = $. + 1 if $end < $start;
```

After replacing the file reading with an array (careful, there is a difference of one between the array index and the line number), we see that the final file reading loop can be avoided if we pull that iteration into the `for` loop, because we know how many lines there are in total. So to say, we do

```
$end = ($num[$i+1] // $last_line_number) - 1;
```

Hopefully my cleaned up code is indeed equivalent to the original.

Comment: I updated with example cleaned up code that should be faster. Because I don't have test data I'm not sure that it is correct, so I had to fall back to error-prone informal proofs of the program state.

Comment: I think you have indeed understood the script correctly. I have run some tests on my development machine and everything works as expected. I would like to run the code against some larger files and report back if thats OK? I also need to take some time to process your comments, thank you for your thoughtful and detailed input.

Comment: The code runs very well on ActivePerl 5.14.2 but I am having some issues getting it to run on Solaris 5.8.4. It will be tomorrow before I get a chance to look at it again.

Comment: @user1568538 I used syntax that is only available since 5.10. You can get around that by `my $end = (defined $num[$i+1] ? $num[$i+1] : @num) - 1;`

Comment: This is the error:Number found where operator expected at prot_cancel_let_clean_v2.pl line 30, near "]1"
        (Missing operator before 1?)
Bareword found where operator expected at prot_cancel_let_clean_v2.pl line 30, near "1I"
        (Missing operator before I?)
Bareword found where operator expected at prot_cancel_let_clean_v2.pl line 30, near "]IR"
        (Missing operator before IR?)
syntax error at prot_cancel_let_clean_v2.pl line 30, near "P["
  (Might be a runaway multi-line // string starting on line 28)
syntax error at prot_cancel_let_clean_v2.pl line 30, near "[|"

Comment: @user1568538 My script doesn't even have 30 lines, so I have no idea what code you are using. It seems that it has confused what is inside and outside the regex. But I would have to see the *exact* code to determine the problem. (Edit your question, or comment with a pastebin link or something).

Comment: I had added a couple of comments and two close filehandles that clearly didn't work. The code works with the amendments for pre 5.10. The only issue is that it doesn't print the last record from the file to STDOUT. I am using a redirect to capture the STDOUT and it is this ouput that is being used. The $cancfile is just a record of what has been removed. When tested on a Solaris server the run time drops from 12+ hours to a few seconds. A wonderful example of how to do it, Thank you!

Comment: @user1568538 I found the error: it should be `my $end = (defined $num[$i+1] ? $num[$i+1] : @lines) - 1;` – `@num` changed to `@lines`.

Comment: working as expect with that change and run time is under five seconds now, perfect!